# Write pandas dataframe to xlsm file (Excel with Macros enabled), 'workbook' has no attribute 'add_vba_project'

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xlsx

Despite this question already being answered, suggesting that vbaProject.bin is used to extract the VbaProject.bin macro file from a real xlsm file and insert it into the new file. However, I'm getting the following error (see below)

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPyKi.png)

Comment: Welcome! Please do not post images, post the code in text format.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.